# Sound file runs fine on Desktop with LibGDX, but crashes on android device

Tags: javascript, android-studio, libgdx

Right now, I am programming a video game in Android Studio with LibGDX that can run on both Desktop and Android devices.

In certain parts of the game, I want to play a sound effect using a Sound variable:

```
public Sound sound5;
```

In the show() function of the Screen, I am initializing the sound by setting the path to the sound effect audio file:

```
sound5 = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("C:/Users/coder/Desktop/Catacombs - Copy/android/res/raw/nff_confirm_02.wav"));
```

Then, in the hide() function, I dispose the sound variable:

```
sound5.dispose();
```

In one of my button's functions, I play the sound:

```
sound5.play();
```

When I run my game on Desktop, the game runs perfectly fine and plays the sound file whenever I press a button, but when I try to run my game on an Android device, the game crashes with a FileNotFoundException as soon as it starts up. Here is the log for the crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 24292
              Process: com.efe.gamedev.catacombs, PID: 24651
              com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading audio file: C:/Users/coder/Desktop/Catacombs - Copy/android/res/raw/nff_confirm_02.wav
              Note: Internal audio files must be placed in the assets directory.
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newSound(AndroidAudio.java:181)
                  at com.efe.gamedev.catacombs.MenuScreen.show(MenuScreen.java:117)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
                  at com.efe.gamedev.catacombs.CatacombsGame.showMenuScreen(CatacombsGame.java:25)
                  at com.efe.gamedev.catacombs.CatacombsGame.create(CatacombsGame.java:20)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:311)
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1537)
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1253)
               Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/Users/coder/Desktop/Catacombs - Copy/android/res/raw/nff_confirm_02.wav
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method)
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:370)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.getAssetFileDescriptor(AndroidFileHandle.java:237)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newSound(AndroidAudio.java:176)
                  at com.efe.gamedev.catacombs.MenuScreen.show(MenuScreen.java:117) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61) 
                  at com.efe.gamedev.catacombs.CatacombsGame.showMenuScreen(CatacombsGame.java:25) 
                  at com.efe.gamedev.catacombs.CatacombsGame.create(CatacombsGame.java:20) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:311) 
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1537) 
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1253)
```

The audio file "nff_confirm_02.wav" does exist in the raw folder inside of my res folder. The file name does not have any capitals or spaces, so that shouldn't be a problem.

I have tried multiple file paths to the audio file, like:

```
sound5 = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("android/res/raw/nff_confirm_02.wav"));
```

or just:

```
sound5 = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("raw/nff_confirm_02.wav"));
```

However, both must be incorrect because the game crashes on both Desktop and Android.
I am not sure what I need to do to prevent the Android device from giving me a FileNotFoundException.

By the way, I looked in the log for the crash, and I found that it said:

```
Note: Internal audio files must be placed in the assets directory.
```

There is an "assets" directory in the android directory of my LibGDX project, but whenever I try to paste the audio file that I am using into the assets directory, it automatically puts the file into the "res" directory in the android directory, so I didn't think that was the problem.

Any advice is welcome to help me be able to play a sound file in LibGDX, without my file path giving me a FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your assets should be inside `assets` folder of android module in LibGDX project.

Please take a look of Project Explorer :

[image]

Create sound object in this way whenever you want :

```
Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/nff_confirm_02.wav"));
sound.play();
```

For Desktop, Configuration should be like this :

[image]

Cross check **Working directory** path.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see a Working directory path in my Desktop Configuration. I am using Android Studio 3.0.1, which is not the latest version. Is that the problem?

Comment: I just updated to Android Studio 3.2.1, and I still don't see a Working Directory option in Desktop Configuration. My Gradle version is 3.3, which is not the latest version. Is that affecting why I can't see the Working directory path?

Comment: can you share configuration, what you've ??

Comment: Okay, it ended up that the reason that all my files that I put in the "assets" folder automatically went to the "res" folder, was because I was making the "sounds" folder be an android resource directory with a raw resource type. I fixed it by making the "sounds" folder by a normal directory, which was a very simple fix.

Comment: In the end, I didn't need to do anything with the Working directory path.